# Initialize multiple objects with names from array

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to create multiple instances of a structure in an elegant way.

I have an array with names:

```
let instanceNames = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday"]
```

and a structure to go along with that:

```
struct days {
var date = ""
var description = ""
var otherValue = ""
}
```

What I want to end up with is this:

```
var Monday = days()
var Tuesday = days()
var Wednesday = days()
var Thursday = days()
var Friday = days()
```

---

Is there a way to do this in one line, I tried this but of course it didn't work:

```
for day in instanceNames {
var day = days()
}
```

---

Any help would be appreciated much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there's no way to assign to many local variables in that way, your best bet would be to use a dictionary to do this:

```
var d = Dictionary<String, days>()
for day in instanceNames {
    d[day] = days()
}
```

Then you can address them with expressions like `d["Monday"]`.

Comment: Thanks, bit of a pity that there is no really simple way to do this but it'll work.

Answer (score 2):

You can't assign an instance to a `day` value. `day` is a string in your case.
If you want to create instance per day, you can do the following:

```
struct Day {
    var date = ""
    var description = ""
    var otherValue = ""
}

var days : Day[] = []
for _ in instanceNames {
    var day = Day()
    days.append(day)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following, it might work for you.

```
let instanceNames = ["Monday", "Tuesday"]

struct days {
    var date: String
    var description: String
    var otherValue: String
}

for day in instanceNames{
    var day1 = days(date: day, description: "great", otherValue:"Awesome");
    println(day1.date)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing this:

```
struct week {
var monday = day()
var tuesday = day()
var wednesday = day()
..
}
```

and

```
struct day {
var date = ""
var description = ""
..
}
```

Now I can initialize all those days with just one line of code:

```
currentWeek = week()
```

and objects for all days of a week are created. I can then access them via

```
currentWeek.monday
```

for example.

Thanks for the help!